# How do I pass a partial view with a specific model if another partial view is using a different model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to view the cart on my page which is already using a different view model. Here is my Layout:

```
@RenderBody()
....
<div id="cd-shadow-layer"></div>
<div id="cd-cart">
    @Html.Partial("_ItemsCartPartial", (Model as List<TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Order>))
</div>
```

The view that is rendered in the body is using

```
@model TShirtEmpAdmin.ViewModels.ShirtOrdersViewModel
```

THe html partial is rendering

```
@model IEnumerable<TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Order>
```

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ViewModels.ShirtOrdersViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Models.Order'.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe add an Order property to ShirtOrdersViewModel?

Comment: What model does the `_ItemsCartPartial.cshtml` use. You need to pass it the same type.

Comment: Is your "ShirtOrdersViewModel" is inherited from "Order"? if yes then you just need an explicit case. If no then you can use utilize the implicit conversion operator overload. Create a method which will automatically convert one object to another based on implementation of overload method.

Comment: @StephenMuecke _ItemsCartPartial.Cshtml inherits model IEnumerable<TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Order>

Comment: `Order` and `IEnumerable<Order>` are not the same, but the message related to `ShirtOrdersViewModel`. You have not given nearly enough information in your question, but suggest you read through [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ) to understand why the error occurs

Comment: I edited my question to try to make it clearer

Comment: Using `@Html.Partial()` in a layout where the partial declares a model makes no sense (it means you layout can only use one type). And `Model as List<TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Order>` would result in `null` since `ShirtOrdersViewModel` cannot be cast to `List<TShirtEmpAdmin.Models.Order>`

Comment: Are you wanting every page using that layout to display your collection of Orders? If so, then use `@{ Html.RenderAction(...)` to call a server method that returns a partial view or all Orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because your view is using a model that is typeof `ShirtOrdersViewModel` and its layout is calling a partial that expects `List<Order>`. Because the layout has

```
@Html.Partial("_ItemsCartPartial", (Model as List<Order>))
```

you are attempting to cast the model which is `ShirtOrdersViewModel` to `List<Order>` which fails and the result of that is the same as

```
@Html.Partial("_ItemsCartPartial", null)
```

When you pass `null` as the model, the method uses the `ViewDataDictionary` of the main view and so the method now passes `ShirtOrdersViewModel` to a partial expecting `List<Order>`, hence the exception.

Your current implementation means that your layout can only be used by a view whose model is `List<Order>` (or is a model that derives from a BaseModel which contains a property `List<Order>` in which case you could use `@Html.Partial("_ItemsCartPartial", Model.MyListOfOrdersProperty)`). However that would be the wrong approach in your case, and instead you should create a method that returns a `PartialView` of the orders, for example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Orders()
{
    List<Order> orders = .... // get orders for the current user
    return PartialView("_Orders", orders);
}
```

and the `_Orders.cshtml` file would have `@model List<Order>` and the code to display them. Then in the layout, render the results of the partial using

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Orders", yourControllerName); }
```