# Uploading images from different input files in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I want to upload Images to a database. The database contains url images and images uploads to folder in file system. I have the following tables in the database,

1. `Furniture`
2. `MainFileDetails` (1-1 relationship with `Furniture`) where store the main image
3. `FileDetails` (1-Many relationship with `Furniture`) where we store other images associated with `Furniture`.

Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Furniture furniture , HttpPostedFileBase fileTwo, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            fileTwo = Request.Files[i];
            if (fileTwo != null && fileTwo.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileNameTwo = Path.GetFileName(fileTwo.FileName);
                MainFileDetails mainFileDetail = new MainFileDetails()
                {
                    FileName = fileNameTwo,
                    Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileNameTwo),
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    FurnitureId = furniture.FurnitureId
                };
                var pathMain = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/MainPage/"), mainFileDetail.Id + mainFileDetail.Extension);
                fileTwo.SaveAs(pathMain);
                db.Entry(mainFileDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                FileDetail fileDetail = new FileDetail()
                {
                    NameFile = fileNameTwo, //or mainFileDetail.FileName
                    Extension = Path.GetExtension(fileNameTwo), //or mainFileDetail.Extension
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    FurnitureId = furniture.FurnitureId //or mainFileDetail. FurnitureId
                };
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/"), fileDetail.Id + fileDetail.Extension);
                file.SaveAs(path);
                db.Entry(fileDetail).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
        }
        db.Entry(furniture).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Changes in \"{0}\" has been saved", furniture.Name);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryId", "Name", furniture.CategoryId);
    return View(furniture);
}
```

My View:

```
@model FurnitureStore.Entities.Furniture
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Furnitures", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    ....
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FurnitureId)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    .... // more inputs for properties of the model
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, "Category")
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = 
    // Main file
    <input type="file" name="fileTwo" />
    @if(Model.MainFileDetails.Id == null)
    {
        <div class="form-control-static">No image</div>
    }
    else
    {
        <img src="~/Upload/MainPage/@(Model.MainFileDetails.Id + Model.MainFileDetails.Extension)"  width="240" height="240" />
    }
    // Other files
    <input type="file" name="file" multiple="multiple" />
    <ul class="attachment">
        @foreach (var item in Model.FileDetails)
        {
            <li style="list-style-type:none; display:inline;">
                <img src="~/Upload/@(item.Id + item.Extension)" />
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="@item.Id" class="deleteItem">X</a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"  />
}
```

But I have a problem. All photo just uploads to the `Upload/MainPage` folder. I want to upload photo separately to MainPage in one table and separately to gallery (other table).

How can I fix my code, because last uploaded photo in gallery table replaces photo in MainPage?

Comment: Not clear what you asking. You have 2 parameters for `HttPostedFileBase` in you method, each accepts a single file, but you indicate you want a single file plus multiple files, that should be `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. But then you ignore them and just loop through `Request.Files[i]` so you do not even know which files belongs in the main table and the other table. What are the 2 inputs in your view for selecting files?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi , update my question , add my view , i want to upload separately in different tables photo , but my program "thinks" that two different input files is same thing

Comment: Yo have inputs named `file` and `fileTwo` so you parameter should be `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> fileTwo, HttpPostedFileBase file`). So just save `file` to the main table and loop through each file in `fileTwo` and save those to the other table (do not use `Request.Files`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke "(do not use Request.Files") Explain this , please , I don't understand what you mean. Can u show please, some part of code that fix y problem?

Comment: You have 2 parameters in your method that are bound to your file inputs. Why in the world would you ignore them and use `Request.Files`

Comment: @StephenMuecke what I have to do instread Request.Files? It must be two different loops , yes?

Comment: Read my previous comment

Comment: @StephenMuecke  can u move please our discussion to chat , because I don't have enough reputation and have questions to u

Comment: You do not have enough rep to use chat so I can't. No time now, but a I will add an answer in a few hours (there are lots of other issues in your code that you need to address as well.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay thanks a lot, i'll wait

Comment: I have added an answer that solves the immediate issue, however there are numerous other issues with your code. I will update the answer later showing what your code should be.

Comment: @StephenMuecke okay i'll try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foreach` loop in your controller method is looping through every file you have uploaded, and then you create a new `MainFileDetails` for each file and save it. You need to get the 'main file' from the first file input and save it to `MainFileDetails` and then loop through the files in the second file input and save each of them to `FileDetails`.

To solve the immediate problem, change your method to

```
public ActionResult Edit(Furniture furniture , HttpPostedFileBase fileTwo, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> file)
```

and those parameters will be bound with the values for the file inputs. Then its simply

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (fileTwo != null && fileTwo.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        // create an instance of MainFileDetails and set its properties based on
        // the values of fileTwo and save
    }
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase image in file)
    {
        // create an instance of FileDetails and set its details based on 
        // the values of image and save
    }
    db.Entry(furniture).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    ....
```

---

There are however numerous other potential issues with your code.

- Rule 1. Your editing data, so always use a view model. [What is
  ViewModel in
  MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)
- Its unclear why you need a separate 1 to 1 table for the main image.
  The properties for that could be stored in the `Furniture` table. 
  Alteratively you could just have the 1 to Many table, and have a
  `bool IsMainImage` property which would allow you to easily swap
  which is the main image.
- You images table (`FurnitureImages` would be a more appropriate name)
  should include a auto-incremented `int ID` for the PK and properties
  for the file path and file display name
- If `ModelState` is invalid, you return the view, but all the files
  are lost and the poor user needs to re-select them all again

Your view models should be

```
public class FurnitureVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    [Required( ... )]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    .... // other properties of Furniture that you need in the view
    [Required( ... )]
    public int? Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase MainFile { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> SecondaryFiles { get; set; }
    public ImageVM  MainImage { get; set; }
    public List<ImageVM> SecondaryImages { get; set; }
}
public class ImageVM
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

And the view

```
@model yourAssembly.FurnitureVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Furnitures", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    // Note: no need for a hidden input for the ID property assuming your using the default routing
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    .... // more inputs for properties of the model
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, "Please select")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
    // Main file
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MainFile, new { type = "file" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MainFile)
    if (Model.MainImage != null)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainImage.ID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainImage.Path)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MainImage.DisplayName)
        <img src="@MainImage.Path" alt="@MainImage.DisplayName" />
    }
    // Secondary files
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SecondaryFiles, new { type = "file", multiple = "multiple" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SecondaryFiles)
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.SecondaryImages.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SecondaryImages[i].ID)
        ...
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

And the controller POST method

```
public ActionResult Edit(FurnitureVM model)
{
    // Save the files
    if (model.MainFile != null && model.MainFile.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        string displayName = model.MainFile.FileName;
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(displayName)
        string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), extension)
        string path = Path.Combine("~/Images/", fileName);
        model.MainFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));
        model.MainImage = new ImageVM() { Path = path, DisplayName = displayName };
    }
    foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in model.SecondaryFiles)
    {
        ....
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CategoryList = new SelectList(....); // repopulate the SelectList
        return View(model);
    }
    // Get the data model from the database
    Furniture furniture = db.Furniture.Where(x => x.FurnitureId == model.ID).FirstOrDefault()
    // Update properties based on view model
    furniture.Name = modell.Name;
    ...
    // Update the main image
    if (model.MainImage != null && !model.MainImage.ID.HasValue)
    {
        FurnitureImages image = new FurnitureImages()
        {
            image.Path = model.MainImage.Path;
            image.DisplayName = model.MainImage.DisplayName;
            image.IsMainImage = true;
            furniture.Images.Add(image);
    }
    // Update secondary images
    IEnumerable<ImageVM> newImages = model.SecondaryImages.Where(x => x.ID == null);
    foreach (ImageVM image in newImages)
    {
        .... // add to the collection
    }
    // Save and redirect
}
```

Comment: okay thanks for answer , firstly i tried not change a model just use your first recommendation with foreach ,  i write this code http://pastebin.com/eTjeZPRS just for testing , and it doesn't work , can u review it please?  Now I have Exception in View  @if(Model.MainFileDetails.Id == null) "object reference not set to an instance of an object " , i will try to change my model

Comment: The error means that either `Model` or `MainFileDetails` is `null`You need to check it first - `if(Model != null && Model.MainFileDetails != null) { ....` But that is completely unrelated to the question you asked (and I assure that the the answer I gave does solve the issue in your question)

Comment: In any case the error is caused only when you return the view in the GET method because `MainFileDetails` is `null` - nowhere in your view have you generated any inputs for properties of `MainFileDetails` so in the POST method its `null`. I pointed out that your had multiple errors, and I even fixed that one as you can see in the view code of my answer (note the hidden inputs for `MainImage` and `SecondaryImages`)

Comment: explain please structure of database looks like? I use code First and it create database something like this  [table1](http://imgh.us/1_3137.png) and this  [table2](http://imgh.us/2_762.png). You can see another props in tables (Album) I just test your code I don't sure if structure is right

Comment: Those tables do not even relate to the code in your question (which is `Furniture`, `MainFileDetails` and `FileDetails`) so I have no idea what your talking about. If you have another question, then ask another question.

Comment: it's your code  , i create tables  based on your code , you said that i don't need separate tables , so i create ImageVM , and delete other Tables (Filedetals and MainFileDetails) and create this one , or I understand your table incorrect??

Comment: `ImageVM` is a view model, not a data model. I suggested you have a table named `FurnitureImages` with a one-many relation ship with the `Furniture` table (which would have a similar structure to the `table 1` you showed.

Comment: But in my answer I showed you how to correct your existing code in the 1st two code snippets which works and will save you images correctly. Are you saying that it is not saving your images?

Comment: oh it's view model , my bad ,  sorry , i miss it , but if  i create this class view model  , does entity framework asks me to add this moidel to database or it will ignored? okay i got it ,Sorry for  my ignorance,

Comment: View models have no relationship to data models. Create a separate folder (say `ViewModels`) and add you view model classes there.

Comment: okay , i got it , can i ask u something? I don't understand what i have to write in  if (model.MainImage != null && !model.MainImage.ID.HasValue) and what i have to do in foreach , can  u write 1 line code to understand what to write , please

Comment: That will depend on how your real database tables and models are set up. I am about to sign off for a couple of hours but I will add some sample code later. But the first part of my question answers your question and the 2nd part is just extra code to show you the correct way to approach this. If the first part did not solve result in saving the images (which I assume it did not since you have not accepted the answer), then you should let me know what failed.

Comment: I have added some sample code in side that `if` block. It assumes you have one table named `FurnitureImages` that has a one-many relationship with `Furniture`

Comment: thanks , yes , i create FurnitureImages as you say and read about viewmodels , now it's night in my timezone :) i'll try your code , if something go wrong  i write here , thanks for helping and  Thank you for your time

Comment: okay hello again , i have a several questions to you , i'm stuck in  foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in model.SecondaryFiles)  , is it right in my code? Or i must create an instance in this block?? because you explain about instance , but is it possible do it? Look at my code please http://pastebin.com/qt9UNGB7

Comment: I gave your an answer which solved the problem in your question (the first part of my answer). But still you refuse to accept it. The second part of my question was extra code showing the outline of the code you should be using and is not directly related to the question. If you have questions about that, then ask a new question with the code you have tried.

Comment: okay i asked new question if i need , I know i make you seek , but in last i have an exception The model item is of type System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Furniture_6E0427CB015001BD6A45794C4DBA1423DB21DD5574A267E56C626A0B7606AB8C but requires a model item of type  FurnitureStore.ModelView.FurnitureVM. Thanks a lot , i accept your answer for this long time

Comment: The reason for the exception is explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ). But I cannot keep flipping between incomplete code in pastebin links which is why you need to ask a new question

Comment: No time just now. Will take a look in about 2 hours.