# Correct method of passing correct data model to partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015

**Problem:**
Error message upon passing viewmodel to partial view.

**Main page: Index.cshmtl, uses class DivisionModel**

```
@model  DivisionViewModel

@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@*<h2>Division</h2>*@
<div>

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="divTabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>

    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- Home -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Company/Division/_prtDivision.cshtml", new addDivisionViewModel())
        </div>
```

**Partial view: _prtDivision.cshmtl, uses addDivisionViewModel**

```
@model addDivisionViewModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Company/Division/Index.cshtml";
}

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>add division</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("addDivision", "Division", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(false, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

However, when I pass 'addDivionsViewModel to the view.

i.e. on index page in the tabpanel

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Company/Division/_prtDivision.cshtml", new addDivisionViewModel())
```

I get the below error message:

[image]

Indicating the passed model is incorrect...
If I then change the calling method to:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Company/Division/_prtDivision.cshtml", new DivisionViewModel())
```

or

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Company/Division/_prtDivision.cshtml", Model)
```

I get the below message:

[image]

So, irrespective of the what model I send to the partial view, VS tells me it wants the opposite one ?

I've been digging around a lot on this topic, for something that would appear relatively simple it doesn't really turn out to be all that simple...

**What I've tried:**

- Adding addDivisionViewModel as property of DivisionModel and passing Model.addDivisionViewModel to _prtDivision.cshtml
- Following above but assigning the property to created variable just before sending (i.e. `@{ var m = Model.addDivisionViewModel}`)
- Passing `Model` and separating the `.addDivisionViewModel` from model.
  Loosing functionality and loosing references to original data. I.e. data cannot be displayed (too deep into tree structure => `Model.addDivisonViewModel.Division.DivisionName`)
  and about a hundred other methods seen on the web...

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi you want to pass orginal model from cotnroller's action method to partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your partial view has a model which is `addDivisionViewModel` but it also includes

```
Layout = "~/Views/Company/Division/Index.cshtml";
```

and the `Index.cshtml` view has a model which is `DivisionViewModel`

It cannot be both (unless one is deriving from the other). Remove the `Layout = ".."` line from your partial view (a partial view should not have a layout)

Comment: Isn't it funny how these things are so very often so very simple...:-) cheers

Comment: I wrote [this community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ) thinking I had covered every possibility for generating that error but I was wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Make your partialviewLayout as null

```
@model addDivisionViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```