# How to pass values entered in one html page and display the executed result in another html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to select `Quarter and Year` then on submit those two values should be passed to my stored proc `"SummaryProc"` and after executing it will pass the rows for ID..... Please guide me if the code i have written is fine. I am missing out on the link as I am unable to understand how to link all these. The working app will be `"Enter Quarter & Year in _Summary.cshtml -> Pass values to Controller -> Execution in Repository code -> rows returned from stored proc to be displayed in SummaryTable.cshtml"`

_Summary.cshtml

```
                     <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Period:</label>
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        @Html.DropDownList("Quarter", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q1", Value = "1" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q2", Value = "2" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q3", Value = "3" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q4", Value = "4" }) }, "--Select Quarter--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Quarter" })
                        <br />
                        @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2016", Value = "2016" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }) }, "--Select Year--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "Year" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-offset-4" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Controller code:

```
  [ActionName("_Summary")]
            [HttpPost]

            public ActionResult _Summary(FloorPlanViewModel model, FormCollection form)
            {

                SummaryConfiguration sumConfig = new SummaryConfiguration();
            sumConfig.Quarter = Convert.ToInt32(form["Quarter"]);
            sumConfig.Year = Convert.ToInt32(form["Year"]);
            var details = floorService.SummaryProc(sumConfig.Quarter, sumConfig.Year);
            return PartialView("SummaryTable", details);

            }
```

Code to execute stored procedure:

```
 public IEnumerable<SummaryConfiguration> SummaryProc(int Quarter, int Year)
          {
              var model = new List<SummaryConfiguration>();


              using (var dbCmd = defaultDB.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.SummaryProc"))
              {
                  defaultDB.AddInParameter(dbCmd, "Quarter", System.Data.DbType.Int32, Quarter);
                  defaultDB.AddInParameter(dbCmd, "Year", System.Data.DbType.Int32, Year);
                  var varCmd = defaultDB.ExecuteReader(dbCmd);

                  while (varCmd.Read())
                  {
                      // add items in the list
                      model.Add(new SummaryConfiguration()
                      {
                          ID = Convert.ToString(varCmd["ID"]),
                        //rest of the code
                      });
                  }
              }
              return model;
          }
```

Comment: You need to specify the view name if you want to return a different view. But why in the world are you not binding to your model instead of using code like `Convert.ToInt32(form["Quarter"]`. And you will get better performance if you were to use ajax to post the option values and update the existing view with a partial view of the table.

Comment: And your `SummaryProc` method returns `IEnumerable<SummaryConfiguration>` so the `@foreach (var item in Model.sumConfig)` makes no sense (`IEnumerable<T>` does not contain any properties) and your code would just throw [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: @StephenMuecke so can i just use '@foreach (var item in Model)' ?

Comment: Yes you could (but then you not displaying the selected options in the new view which does not make for a good UI)

Comment: in the next view i need to display lineid, project etc in the table. I have made some changes to the code..let me update the question

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have made some changes to the code. Now I am getting a page where I need to enter Quarter & year. but on submit nothing is happening. Its even not hitting the breakpoiubts in the controller

Comment: Yes I know, but you will also want to display (say) 'Results for Quarter 1, 2017' so the user knows what they are looking at :) And `_Summary.cshtml` has nothing to do with `@model IList<SummaryConfiguration>`, and it needs a different model (one with properties for `Quarter` and `Year`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150673/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-beginner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to handle this without using ajax is to have a single GET method and view that posts back to the method.

Start by creating a view model to represent your view

```
public class SummaryConfigurationVM
{
    public int Quarter { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SummaryConfiguration> Configurations { get; set; }
    public IEnuemrable<SelectListItem> QuarterList { get; set; }
    public IEnuemrable<SelectListItem> YearListList { get; set; }
}
```

and add any validation attributes that may be applicable to `Quarter` and `Year` (for example a `[Range]` attribute)

and the your controller method will be

```
public ActionResult Summary(int? quarter, int? year)
{
    IEnumerable<SummaryConfiguration> configurations = new List<SummaryConfiguration>();
    if (quarter.HasValue && year.HasValue)
    {
        configurations = floorService.SummaryProc(quarter.Value, year.Value);
    }
    SummaryConfigurationVM model = new SummaryConfigurationVM()
    {
        Quarter = quarter,
        Year = year,
        Configurations = configurations,
        QuarterList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Q1", Value = "1" },
            ....
        },
        YearList = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            ....
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Note that you also need to consider validating that the values of `quarter` and `year` fall in the expected range.

Your view will then be

```
@model SummaryConfigurationVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Summary", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Quarter)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Quarter, Model.QuarterList, "--Select Quarter--")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Quarter)

    .... // ditto for Year

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Configurations.FirstOrDefault().LineID)</th>
            ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach( var item in Model.Configurations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LineID)</td>
                .... // other properties of SummaryConfiguration
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You might also consider rendering the `<table>` in side a `@if (Model.Configuraton.Any()) {` block (and if `false` the display a message noting that no results were found.

Comment: I made changes according to your answer. But when i run the app Its not opening the page where i need to enter Quarter and year.. throws an exception "

[ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'quarter' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult SummaryTable(Int32, Int32)' in 'USTGlobal.WorkBench.UI.Controllers.FloorPlanController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters]"

Comment: If your want to be able to navigate to the page and not pass any parameters, then just make the parameters `nullable` - i.e. `public ActionResult Summary(int? quarter, int? year)` but then you will definitely need to validate that they are not `null` before running your query

Comment: For example if either are `null` then you would set your `Configurations` to an empty list (and not call the `SummaryProc()` method. Give me 10 min and I'll update the answer with a typical example, but you may need to modify it based on your logic

Comment: i made the changes . that particular exception is gone now. But I am getting another exception at SummaryProc about the casting "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types."

Comment: Did you use `quarter.Value, year.Value` when calling the method?

Comment: In my question you can see "Code to execute stored procedure: LineID = Convert.ToString(varCmd["LineID"]),...."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150684/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-beginner).