# Html.RenderPartial() ViewDataDictionary moedl is incorect when running on Azure but works on localhost Net Core 1 app

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, asp.net-core

I have the following situation:

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Action()
{
     var actionViewModel = new ActionViewModel()
     {
          ActionOptions = new ActionOptionsViewModel()
     }

     return View(actionViewModel)
}
```

View:

```
@model ActionViewModel

@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ActionOptions", Model.ActionOptions ); }
```

Partial View:

```
@model ActionOptionsViewModel
```

The exception I am getting is:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ActionOptionsViewModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ActionViewModel'.

Weirdly enough I get this error only when I get deployed this code on Azure but it works locally. Any ideas why this is happening?! I cant reproduce the error on localhost and cant figure out what possible could be different when it comes to rendering a view on localhost and Azure...

Comment: Kinda sounds like some files were not updated.

Comment: @juunas Its updated... the partial view has the correct model specified ..

Comment: Since the code you have shown cannot possibly generate that error, best guess is that it's due to code in a POST method where you return a view because `ModelState` is invalid (and you return `ActionOptionsViewModel` to the main view which expects `ActionViewModel`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I dont get to the post method. The error happens when hitting the get and then in the returned view. If I intentionally change the partial view model to 'ActionViewModel' then I get the same error locally.

Comment: The code you have shown cannot generate that error. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ) for the possible causes

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am creating the models before passing them to the view using the “new” keyword so they can not be null and I don’t get the exception when running on localhost it happens only on Asure. so I was wondering what could be different when it renders the view on Azure

Comment: The error states your passing an instance of `ActionOptionsViewModel` to a view/partial view (or layout) which has `@model ActionViewModel` which is not the code you have shown, so I can only assume you have omitted some relevant code (note also that I have seen issues with naming a method `Action` although probably not related in your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cant reproduce the error on localhost and cant figure out what possible could be different when it comes to rendering a view on localhost and Azure

I would recommend you empty your web content on Azure and republish your application to azure to narrow this issue. For Azure Web App, you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) or [connect to your site via ftp](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/) to empty your web content under `D:\home\site\wwwroot` folder. Also, you could [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug). For Azure Cloud Service or Azure VM, you could remote to your server and empty the web content folder.