# How to show a dropdown list in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I'm having some troubles with Models and ViewModels.

I need list all **bills** and the **users** in the same view. (users in a dropdown list)

Also: When to use `IEnumerable<T>`? Because depending I change the view change the error message.

#### Model

```
public class Bill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public Card Card { get; set; }
    public int CardId { get; set; }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
public class UserBills
{
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> User { get; set; }
    public Bill Bill { get; set; }
}
```

#### View

```
@*@model IEnumerable<Nucontrol.Models.Bill>*@
@model IEnumerable<Nucontrol.ViewModels.UserBills>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bill.Card.Number)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bill.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bill.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bill.Category)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Bill.Amount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Bill.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Bill.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Split", "Split",  new { id = item.Bill.Id }, new { data_target = "#myModal", data_toggle = "modal" })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

<!-- List all users -->
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => User.Identity.Name, new SelectList(User.Identity.Name, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = _context.Users.ToList();
    var bills = _context.Bills.ToList();

    var viewModel = new UserBills
    {
        User = users
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-bind-the-value-to-razor-dropdownlist-in-aspnet-mvc5/

Comment: Can you add your Bill and ApplicationUser Models. Are you trying to show all Bills for a single user based on the selected user in the drop down? Can you explain what you are trying to achieve a bit more.

Comment: I think this DDLF doesn't make sense: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => User.Identity.Name, new SelectList(User.Identity.Name, "Id", "Name"), "", new { @class = "form-control" })`. You need to use `IEnumerable<T>` inside viewmodel class to build `SelectList` from that. Also often `User.Identity.Name` set from the cookie or user login instead of DDLF selection.

Comment: I need list all bills and all users in the same view

Comment: You can use `UserManager` and `User = userManager.Users.ToList()` to build all user names list, then use `new SelectList(Model.User)` in DDLF context. Also `IIdentity.Name` is getter property, you can only obtain its value but can't set it directly without setting `HttpContext.User` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in sample code provided:

1) The `DropDownListFor` uses `User.Identity.Name` property as model binding, which actually derived from [`IIdentity.Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity.name(v=vs.110).aspx) which is getter-only property. Declare another property with setter available which holds user ID in your viewmodel.

2) Passing `UserBills` viewmodel into view which bound to `IEnumerable<UserBills>` model may cause [`InvalidOperationException`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ). You need to use either passing `IEnumerable<UserBills>` from controller or define `@model UserBills`.

3) I suggest you use `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to create `DropDownListFor` items from `IEnumerable<ApplicationUser>` generated by identity data context and pass it to view (see also [IdentityUser properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613256(v=vs.108).aspx)).

Here is initial solution based from my thought:

**Model**

```
public class UserBills
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Users { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var users = _context.Users.ToList();
    var bills = _context.Bills.ToList();
    var viewModel = new UserBills
    {
        Users = users.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Value = x.Id.ToString(), Text = x.UserName.ToString() }),
        Bills = bills
    }

    return View(viewModel);    
}
```

**View**

```
@model Nucontrol.ViewModels.UserBills

@foreach (var item in Model.Bills)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Card.Number)
        </td>
        <!-- other properties -->
    </tr>
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserId, Model.Users, "", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

NB: Since you're getting selected user ID from viewmodel binding, it is possible to create [`HttpContext.User`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx) instance and setting `User.Identity.Name` property from that ID.

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for describing and tell the why of the things!