# ASP.NET MVC View not receiving list passed into it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am working on a relatively simple ASP.NET MVC application in C# in Visual Studio. In this situation I am trying to pass a list of objects into my view and then display their names, but I keep getting an error

> Categories does not exist in the current context

Here is the controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    List <CheeseCategory> categories = context.Categories.ToList();
    return View(categories);
}
```

And here is the View:

```
@model CheeseMVC.Models.CheeseCategory

@if (categories != null)
{
    foreach(var category in categories)
    {
        <ul>@category</ul>
    }
}
```

I have done this before, and I can't figure out what is going wrong here, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use `@model IEnumerable<CheeseMVC.Models.CheeseCategory>` since you're passing a list collection to view.

Comment: `@if (categories != null)` needs to be `@if (Model != null)`, but then as soon as you navigate to the page you will get [this exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: And its `foreach(var category in Model)`

Comment: Thank you! All of these combined fixed my issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed in a `List<CheeseCategory>`, but in your Razor file, you said `model` would be just a `CheeseCategory`. The `@model` declaration needs to match what you're passing in.

Also, replace `categories` with `Model` in the `if` statement in the Razor file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke added the detail to address that.