# NopCommerce - Error with Search Box

Tags: c#, razor, nopcommerce

I've got this error :

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.SearchModel', but this dictionary requires a model 
item of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel'
```

the complete error is this :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary 
is of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.SearchModel', but this dictionary requires 
a model item of type 'Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel'. at 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) at 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) at 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ConfigurePage(WebPageBase parentPage) at 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c__DisplayClass3. 
<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) at 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at 
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, 
Action`1 body) at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() at 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive 
(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, 
ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters 
(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult 
actionResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker. 
<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction 
(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller. 
<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState 
innerState) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate 
(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate 
(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, 
ProcessRequestState innerState) at 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate 
(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web 
.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& 
completedSynchronously)
```

I modified my SearchBox.cshtml to insert input that I need Parent Category (cid) and search text (q). So to find the error I delete from the server SearchBox.cshtml and Search.cshtml but it give me the same error.

I'm using nopCommerce version 3.90

Can someone help me to fix this error please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passing model to view from controll  - `Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.SearchModel` and in view page, you using model - `Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.CategoryModel`

Use model `Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.SearchModel` in view page and it'll be fix your issue.