# Core MVC 2 and Ajax wrong data type

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I apologize for the subject topic too general, I have difficulties with Ajax work at all, I'm not able to sent/get up any response. The topic is probably duplicated, but I do not see the error in my code. All tutorials I found say the same thing but it still dont work for me, please take a look.

**View**

```
@model ValueTypeEditViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dodaj Wartość";
    Layout = "_AdminLayout";
}
<div class="col">
    <form asp-action="EditValue" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ValueType.ValueId" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ValueType.TypeId" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ValueType.Value" class="m-1"></label>
            <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Value" class="text-danger"></span></div>
            <input asp-for="ValueType.Value" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        @if (Model.IsSysParam)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.Controller" class="m-1"></label>
                <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Controller" class="text-danger"></span></div>
                <input asp-for="ValueType.Controller" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.Code" class="m-1"></label>
                <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Code" class="text-danger"></span></div>
                <input asp-for="ValueType.Code" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.Description" class="m-1"></label>
                <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.Description" class="text-danger"></span></div>
                <textarea asp-for="ValueType.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.IsSysParam" class="m-1"></label>
                <div><span asp-validation-for="ValueType.IsSysParam" class="text-danger"></span></div>
                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="ValueType.IsSysParam" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        }

        @if (Model.ValueType.ValueId != 0)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.CreateDate" class="m-1"></label>
                <label class="m-1">@Model.ValueType.CreateDate</label>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ValueType.EditDate" class="m-1"></label>
                <label class="m-1">@Model.ValueType.EditDate</label>
            </div>
        }


        @*@if (!Model.IsSysParam)
        {
                        <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-5">
                                 <select id="lbProducts" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Products" size="@Model.ListBoxSize" multiple></select>
                                 <label class="m-1">Lista Przedmiotów</label>
                             </div>
                            <div class="col-1 align-self-center">
                                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                    <button id="addItems" class="btn btn-light mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-5">
                                <select id="lbAddedProducts" class="form-control" size="@Model.ListBoxSize" multiple></select>
                                @*<form method="post">
                    <button asp-page-handler="saveValueItems" id="saveValueItems" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    <button id="removeItems" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
         </div>
         }*@

        <div class="text-left">
            <button class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="submit">Zapisz</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form asp-route="@(Model.IsSysParam ? RouteUrl.Name.SystemList : RouteUrl.Name.CategoryList)" method="post">
        <div class="text-left">
            <input type="hidden" name="isSysParamCategory" value="@Model.IsSysParam.ToString()" />
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn mt-1">Anuluj</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <form method="post">
        @if (!Model.IsSysParam)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <select id="lbProducts" class="form-control" asp-items="Model.Products" size="@Model.ListBoxSize" multiple></select>
                    <label class="m-1">Lista Przedmiotów</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-1 align-self-center">
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button id="addItems" class="btn btn-light mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <select id="lbAddedProducts" class="form-control" size="@Model.ListBoxSize" multiple></select>
                    <button asp-page-handler="saveValueItems" id="saveValueItems" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    <button id="removeItems" class="btn btn-primary mt-1" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </form>
</div>
```

At View you can see comented code started with - '@if (!Model.IsSysParam)'. Firstly I tried to fire Ajax from 'main' from with `asp-page-handler="saveValueItems"` at `button`. Then I added nested form in form with post (there is commented too), in the end I tried to created separeted form in the bottom of example. (by the way, I'm a beginner with mvc and don't really know if I can nesting form in form)

- All the time I get the same error

**Ajax**

```
$(saveValueItems).click(function () {
            var data = [];
            var addedItems = $(addedItemList).find('option');
            for (var i = 0; i < addedItems.length; i++) {
                var item = addedItems[i];
                data.push($(item).val());
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/admin/category/editvalue/96/35?handler=saveValueItems",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('spoko');
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        })
```

I hardcoded url to be sure I send request to good action. I have this in mind to test only with this one item/values.

**Controller**

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.Category + RouteUrl.Slash + "editvalue/{typeId?}/{valueId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.CategoryEditValueAjax)]
    public ActionResult OnPostSaveValueItems([FromBody] int[] arrValueItems)
    {
        string test = "Hello Response Back";
        return new JsonResult(test);
    }
```

**Startup.cs**
I added to Startup.cs `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` before `AddMvc()` too

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
services.AddMvc();
```

[image]

[image]

**Question:**
I do not understand why I am sending the wrong data type. I want to send an int table and I receive a message that I'm sending ValueType and the view is expecting ValueTypeEditViewModel.
I do not know where to look for the cause of the error

**1 Edit:**
**All actions for edit page**

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.System + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.SystemCreateValue)]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.Category + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.CategoryCreateValue)]
        public ViewResult CreateValue(int typeId, bool isSysParamCategory)
        {
            return View(RouteUrl.Edit + RouteUrl.Value, new ValueTypeEditViewModel(typeId, isSysParamCategory, repositoryProduct.Products, Convert.ToInt32(repository.GetSysParamByCode(SysParams.ProductListBoxSize))));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.System + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}/{valueId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.SystemEditValue)]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.Category + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}/{valueId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.CategoryEditValue)]
        public ViewResult EditValue(int typeId, int valueId)
        {
            bool isSysParamCategory = repository.GetCategoryByTypeId(typeId).IsSysParam;
            return View(RouteUrl.Edit + RouteUrl.Value, new ValueTypeEditViewModel(repository.GetValue(typeId, valueId), isSysParamCategory, repositoryProduct.Products, Convert.ToInt32(repository.GetSysParamByCode(SysParams.ProductListBoxSize))));
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.System + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}/{valueId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.SystemEditValue)]
        [Route(RouteUrl.Admin + RouteUrl.Slash + RouteUrl.Category + RouteUrl.Slash + "[action]/{typeId?}/{valueId?}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.CategoryEditValue)]
        public IActionResult EditValue(AureliaCMS.Models.ValueType valueType)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveValueType(valueType);
                return View(RouteUrl.Save, new SaveCategoryType(repository.GetCategoryByTypeId(valueType.TypeId).IsSysParam, valueType.Value, false));
            }
            else
            {
                return View(valueType);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the error is because of your ajax call... can you show us your controllers action that renders the view, I mean before saving it.

Comment: I've just edited the post

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ

Comment: my ajax all the time referred to the public IActionResult EditValue (AureliaCMS.Models.ValueType valueType) insted of OnPostSaveValueItems. 

offtop:
anyway when working on this view / controller I had to give up with ajax for other reasons :(