# Select Tag Helper Works for SelectedAlertIndex, but LoadAlert() action doesn't load new view page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, drop-down-menu, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my form in AlertSelect.cshtml:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.AlertViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "AlertSelect";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CapCategoryLayout.cshtml";
}

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>

    @{
    <h4>@Model.Alerts.Count Alerts</h4>

    <form>
        <select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">
            <option>Select one</option>
        </select>
        <asp-controller ="Alerts" asp-action="LoadAlert" method="post">
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="LoadAlert" value="LoadAlert" />
    </form>
}
```

And this is my LoadAlert() controller action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult LoadAlert(Alert obj, string LoadAlert)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LoadAlert))
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Alert loaded successfully";
        }
        return View("/Views/Alerts/Index", obj);
    }
```

AlertSelect.cshtml displays the standard header and left column and the drop down list and when selected and submitted, the page resets instead of displaying /Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml with the data filled in correctly. However the url reflects the selected item: http://localhost:61453/alerts/AlertSelect?SelectedAlertIndex=2&LoadAlert=LoadAlert.

I'm close but clearly missing something and any help would very welcome. I'd also like to display the selected item on the index.cshtml page to reinforce for the user the alert message they're working on, but the viewmodel (with two properties) for the Select Tag Helper is different from the model (with 16 properties) for the index page.

---

Made the change to my form per both comments and answer below, and instead of returning the view specified in LoadAlert() I have a mismatch of models: "InvalidOperationException:

```
 The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 
'edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires 
 a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert]'.
```

AlertSelect.cshtml  specifies:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.AlertViewModel
```

Alert.cs specifies:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace edxl_cap_v1_2.Models
{
    public class Alert
    {
        [Key]
        public int AlertIndex { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Alert_Identifier { get; set; }
        public string Sender { get; set; }
        public DateTime Sent { get; set; }
...
```

/Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml specifies:

```
@model IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert>
@using edxl_cap_v1_2.Models

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_CapCategoryLayout.cshtml";
}
```

and _CapCategoryLayout specifies:

```
@model edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.ContentViewModels.AlertViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

I'm still not seeing where

```
The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 
'edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert'
```

comes into play except as the namespace of Alert.cs. What do I need to change to keep out of these type mismatches?

Comment: Because by default, your `<form>` makes a GET, not a POST. You need to specify `method="post"` (or use the TagHelper to generate the tag which will add that by default)

Comment: Note that your `<asp-controller ="Alerts" asp-action="LoadAlert" method="post">` makes no sense - those attributes need to be inside the `<form>` tag

Comment: For the exception being generated in your edited code, refer [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: Thanks @Muecke for the link. Seems like, from examples in link,  my LoadAlert() controller action in original question above is sending single alert model instead of IEnumerable alert model, but I'm not sure how to fix this? What I want is the whole list of alert properties filling index.cshtml view page (data from a single alert record with the Alert_Identifier  that matches SelectedAlertIndex from the drop down list--and that part now works.)

Comment: I'm really trying to learn my way through this. I understand there's a mismatch, but not how to fix it. The form seems to work correctly in that the drop down list allows a user to select the Alert_Identifier for the alert message to be edited/worked on, but the LoadAlert() seems to be sending a single alert where the index.cshtml wants the IEnumerable<edxl_cap_v1_2.Models.Alert> which is the list of 15 data elements whose values make up the Alert Data Category of the overall Alert Message. There are four data categories that should work the same way as the Alert Data Category.

Comment: Your `Index.cshtml` requires `@model IEnumerable<Alert>`, therefore if you want to return that view in the `LoadAlert()` POST method, then you need to return a `IEnumerable<Alert>`, not a single `Alert`. But this makes no sense. You should be redirecting to the `Index()` method, not returning a view

Comment: If you mean: return RedirectToAction("Index", "Alerts"); 
instead of: 
return View("/Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml", obj); 
I get the same mismatch of model types. If that's not what you meant, could you perhaps show me? Please excuse my thickheadedness,, I'm doing as best I can.

Comment: If you redirect to the `Index()` method, you cannot possible get that exception based on the code you have shown (assuming that method returns a model which is `IEnumerable<Alert>`) so I assume you have other code causing the issue. Read the link - it lists all the possible causes of that exception

Comment: I'm still a newbie and hadn't learned to `show code` in my previous comment. So please tell me if you meant I should change `return View("/Views/Alerts/Index.cshtml", obj);` to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Alerts");` or `return RedirectToAction("Index");`? Also I'm a morning person and I don't seem to get your replies until late afternoon or evening, which reduces my concentration. Sorry. I'll attack this again in a.m.

Comment: P.S. Thanks for bearing with me @Stepehn Muecke. I appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, I mean to change it to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Alerts");`

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I must still have something wrong since `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Alerts");` didn't solve the problem. So I started a new question with much more of code included because I don't think I had enough in this question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to define form tag helpers in Core MVC should be like this (see documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1)):

```
<form asp-controller="Alerts" asp-action="LoadAlert" method="post">
    <select asp-for="SelectedAlertIndex" asp-items="@Model.Alert_Identifiers">
        <option>Select one</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="LoadAlert" value="LoadAlert" />
</form>
```

Note that default form submit method is `GET` if unspecified, as described in [form element definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html):

> **method = get|post [CI]**
>
> This attribute specifies which HTTP method will
>   be used to submit the form data set. Possible (case-insensitive)
>   values are "get" (**the default**) and "post".

The `GET` method will pass form values through URL [with query string](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-format), hence you get the URL like following:

```
http://localhost:61453/alerts/AlertSelect?SelectedAlertIndex=2&LoadAlert=LoadAlert
```

Since no `HttpGetAttribute` action method found with those 2 query string parameters, the page will "reset" and displaying the same form again instead returning another view.