# How can I read list from controller into foreach view in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[CandidateScreening.Data.Entities.Patient]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[CandidateScreening.Models.Patient]'.)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Patient = _context.Patients.ToList();
    return View(Patient);
}


@model IEnumerable<CandidateScreening.Models.Patient>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "index";
}
<h2>List Of the Patient</h2>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>firstName</th>
            <th>SurName</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @Html.ActionLink(item.Firstname, "Index", "detail")</td>
                <td> @Html.ActionLink(item.Surname, "Index", "detail")</td>
                <td> @Html.ActionLink(item.Gender, "Index", "detail")</td>


            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

could you tell me why I get this error?
I have try by changing `IEnumerable` to `List` but is not working yet

Comment: You appear to have defined `Patient` in 2 separate assemblies - `CandidateScreening.Data.Entities` and `CandidateScreening.Models` - they are not the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: use the automapper (https://automapper.org/) to map your entities to the CandidateScreening.Models.Patient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumed `Patients` is an Entity Framework data context, `ToList()` will generate list with object type set as `IEnumerable<CandidateScreening.Data.Entities.Patient>`, which doesn't match with object type set by `@model` directive (i.e. `IEnumerable<CandidateScreening.Models.Patient>`).

To solve this issue, simply use `Select()` LINQ query to project entity context into  list of viewmodel class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var Patient = _context.Patients.Select(x => new CandidateScreening.Models.Patient
    {
        // list of properties here
        // example:
        // PatientId = x.PatientId
    }).ToList();    

    return View(Patient);
}
```

Or using query expression as alternative:

```
var Patient = (from patient in _context.Patients
              select new CandidateScreening.Models.Patient
              {
                  // list of properties here
                  // example:
                  // PatientId = patient.PatientId
              }).ToList();
```