# wrong model in partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am trying to add a pagination partial view to my search page. 
I have previously added it to two other pages without any issues, but suddenly this one just bugs out.

**I get the following error:**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Website.Models.SearchViewModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Website.Models.Helpers.PaginationModel'.'
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(Search currentPage, string query, int pageSize = 10, int page = 1)
        {
            var model = new SearchViewModel();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
            {// searchquery is present, go for it!

                var searchResults = Umbraco.TypedSearch(query, true, "MyContentSearcher");
                if (searchResults != null && searchResults.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var searchResult = SearchMapper.Map<SearchModel>(searchResults, Umbraco).OrderByDescending(x=> x.CreateDate);


                    // pagination logic
                    pageSize = currentPage.PageSize > 0 ? currentPage.PageSize : pageSize;
                    model.Pagination = new PaginationModel()
                    {
                        PageNumber = page,
                        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)searchResult.Count() / (double)pageSize),
                        Query = query
                    };
                    var skipAmount = page == 1 ? 0 : ((page - 1) * pageSize);

                    // skip and take amount according to pagination.
                    model.SearchResult = searchResult.Skip(skipAmount).Take(pageSize);

            return View(model);
        }
```

**My Model**

```
public class PaginationModel
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }
```

**My View** 
i call the partial on the search page:

```
@Html.Partial("_pagination", Model.Pagination)
```

**My Partial view**

```
    @model Website.Models.Helpers.PaginationModel

    @if (Model.TotalPages > 1)
    {
        <div class="col-12 margin-top-20">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <nav aria-label="...">
                        <ul class="pagination">
                            <li class="page-item @(Model.PageNumber > 1 ? "" : "disabled")">
                                @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Query))
                                {
                                    <a class="page-link" href="?page=@(Model.PageNumber-1)" tabindex="-1">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a> 
                                } else{
                                    <a class="page-link" href="?query=@(Model.Query)&page=@(Model.PageNumber-1)" tabindex="-1">
                                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                                        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                                    </a>
                                }



                        </li>
                        @for (int i = 1; i <= Model.TotalPages; i++)
                        {
                            <li class="page-item @(Model.PageNumber == i ? "active" : "")">
                                <a class="page-link" href="?page=@i">@i</a>
                            </li>
                        }

                        <li class="page-item @(Model.PageNumber == Model.TotalPages ? "disabled" : "")">
                            <a class="page-link " href="?page=@(Model.PageNumber+1)">
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I dont understand why it confuses the model, i clearly set the model in the controller and when calling the partial view i also only give it the pagination model and no more..

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: please check your parameter "query" which is null or empty?

Comment: i have a check on it, @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Query))

Comment: does  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(query)) return false ?

Comment: In your Index view where the partial is used, what does that model look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, it wasn't the wrong model per say, more that it could be null, and therefore it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `@Html.Partial("_pagination", Model.Pagination)` if `Model.Pagination` is null `Model` gets passed instead of `Model.Pagination` which is what is occurring.

You may have to pass `new PaginationModel()` if `Model.Pagination` is null.

Comment: that removed the error. wierd.. i did not think it could ever be null.

Comment: It is because it is in `if`(` - you might put that `model.Pagination = new PaginationModel()` just after your model declaration, then set its value as you have it.  OR just have `SearchViewModel` constuctor do that

Comment: To avoid the query null or empty you might also create a constructor for `new PaginationModel()` setting its values like the query to a non-null value. (i.e. a default value), lots of ways to consider that scenario resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you have created the model of `SearchViewModel`. See below line:

```
var model = new SearchViewModel();
```

Then, you are passing this to view which is wrong. You should create a model of `PaginationModel` because your view requires it.

Comment: I create a pagination model and set it to the searchviewmodel here: model.Pagination = new PaginationModel()
                    {
                        PageNumber = page,
                        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)searchResult.Count() / (double)pageSize),
                        Query = query
                    };

Comment: @andrelange91 In that case, check your parameter `query` is null or not.

Comment: i have a check on it, @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Query))