# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type error in my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Error while i'm running the code is,

> > The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'XYZ.Domain.CartTotal', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[XYZ.Domain.Items]'.

I saw there'a a lots of answer to this type of question in stack overflow But unfortunately it not success for my scenario,

### Shopping Cart View

```
@model XYZ.Domain.CartTotal
<div class="card-body px-1 px-md-5 pt-5" id="cartpartial">
            @Html.Partial("_Cart",Model)

        </div>
```

### _Cart Partial View

```
@model XYZ.Domain.CartTotal
@foreach (var item in Model.items)
            {
// Some Code Here
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult ShoppingCart()
    {
        ViewBag.LoggedInUser = Session["LoggedInUser"].ToString();
        var model = Session["ItemSession"] as CartTotal;
        return View(model);
    }
```

### My DTO

```
   public class CartTotal
    {
        public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
        // Some properties here
        public List<Items> items { get; } = new List<Items>();
    }
```

I have call a model like this,

```
@model IEnumerable<XYZ.Domain.CartTotal>
```

But it also not success

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: Read the provided link and identify where the exception had thrown. The most possible case is you're using other partial view declared with `@model IEnumerable<Items>`.