# Passing a single object from a controller to a view

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a web-based game built using .netCore 2 and entity framework.

The game works, but I just added a new feature. In one of the views, the user can press a button that creates a new character via a controller.

Here is that controller method:

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> AddCharacter(Guid playerId)
    {
        ICharManagement charMgr = new CharManagementClient();

        Character newCharacter = await charMgr.AddCharacterAsync(
            "Test Character",
            new Guid("1e957dca-3fe1-4214-b251-a96e0106997a")
            );

        var newCharacterObject = newCharacter;
        return View(newCharacterObject);
    }

    The Character object is from an API I use and it looks like this:

        public partial class Character : object
    {
        private System.Guid Id;
        private string Name;
        private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DateCreated;
        private int32 CharPlayer;
        private bool Playable;
    }
```

Stepping through the controller in Visual Studio, I can see that a new Character object is returned and the newCharacterObject looks like this:

```
    Id  "1e957dca-3fe1-4214-b251-a96e0106997a"
    Name "Test Character"
    DateCreated "2/12/2019"
    CharPlayer 3821
    Playable "true"
```

In my view (cshtml), I have the model set to this:

```
    @model IEnumerable<Character>
```

However, when I run it, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>    ViewDataDictionary is of type 'Character',       but this
>    ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Character]'.

So how do I get my view to display a single Character object(newCharacterObject) or how would I convert "newCharacterObject" into what the view needs?

Thanks!

Edit: Formatting

Comment: Are you reusing the view (hence you have/had an `IEnumerable<T>`)? If so, you could wrap your returned model into something like `List<Character>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need **one** character model, you can just use `@model Character` at the top of your cshtml

IEnumerable is used for iterating through a collection of objects.