# Convert Dropdown value from string to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have code for a DropDownList in C# with MVC. And the value of that is passed as a string. But, I want that as an integer. How should I convert it on the controller before `SaveChanges()`, because it is throwing an error.

Here is my View code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DesignationID, "DesignationID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("DesignationID", new SelectList(ViewBag.Designationid, "Value", "text"),"Select Designation", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DesignationID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
// POST: Employee/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    try
    {
        employeeService.Insert(employee);
        unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View(ex);
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Pal.Entities.Models.Employee'.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Can you show instance of employee which you are inserting i.e. `employee`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: You might want to [check the ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api) before trying to store that employee

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on:

1. You are getting a `DbUpdateException` (for reasons so far unknown).
2. It goes into the `catch`, where you appear to be trying to show the Exception by calling `return View(ex)`, but for that to work the View `Create.cshtml` would need to contain something like `@model System.Exception`. That isn't the case, causing yet another Exception.
   You need to find another way to deal with the Exception info; e.g. call `Logger.Log(ex)` on it, or create an error view `Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` that uses `@model System.Exception`, and then call that View by doing `return View("Error", ex);` in the catch-part.