# dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ShimbaSchool.Models.EventMessageDepartment]'

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im experiencing an error on trying to fetch data from a db using a list scaffolding. The error and the code is as follow.

**My Model:**

```
namespace ShimbaSchool.Models
{
    [Table("tblStaff")]
    public class Staff
    {
        [Key]
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Upload Image")]
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        [Required,MinLength(2),DisplayName("Staff Name")]
        public string StaffName { get; set; }
        [Required,MaxLength(250)]
        [DisplayName("Teacher's Subject")]
        public string StaffSpecialty { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
namespace ShimbaSchool.Controllers
{
    public class StaffController : Controller
    {
        EventMessageDepartmentContext db = new EventMessageDepartmentContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.StaffTable.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

**The View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<ShimbaSchool.Models.Staff>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MyLayout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ImagePath)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StaffName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.StaffSpecialty)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImagePath)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.StaffSpecialty)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StaffId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StaffId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.StaffId })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

On executing i get the error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List 1[ShimbaSchool.Models.Staff]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[ShimbaSchool.Models.EventMessageDepartment]'.

Please help me fix this situation and understand the logic so that there is no next time. To add on i used the same model with another controller and its working fine though the view were rendered on different layouts of the same project.

Comment: Actually the list you are passing from controller method to view is a `List of EventMessageDepartment`, not `List of Staff`. Please check it and pass `List of Staff` from controller method to the view.

Comment: Actually, the EventMessageDepartmentContext you see on the controller is my data context that enable communication to the db.

Comment: Yes! but you have to select the table properly. Better give remote access with team viewer id and pass. I shall fix your problem.

Comment: 1 421 119 183 Cant you rectify from the code i posted>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The model item passed into the dictionary is of type .. but this dictionary requires a model item of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373595/the-model-item-passed-into-the-dictionary-is-of-type-but-this-dictionary-requ)

Comment: The duplicate link above already covers your issue - you're passing `db.StaffTable.ToList()` result to view which has model directive `IEnumerable<ShimbaSchool.Models.Staff>`. This is a well-known problem which occurred when passing wrong type from controller to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the list you are passing from controller method to view is a `List of EventMessageDepartment`, not `List of Staff`. Please check it properly and pass `List of Staff` from controller method to the view.

If you are ensured that the data you are passing to the view is `List<ShimbaSchool.Models.Staff>` then please check your `Layout.cshtml` page. May be there is `@model IEnumerable<EventMessageDepartment>` is referenced.

Comment: it was my layout page, totally forgot I was testing something there

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following?

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.StaffTable.AsEnumerable());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to return an IEnumerable version of your model to the list view.

```
@model IEnumerable<IdentityManager.Models.MerchantDetail>
```

Second, you need to return a list from the database. I am doing it via SQL Server, so this is code I got working.

```
    public IActionResult Merchant_Boarding_List()
        List<MerchantDetail> merchList = new List<MerchantDetail>();
        var model = new MerchantDetail();

        try
        {
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(Common.DB_CONNECTION_STRING_BOARDING))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand("select * from MerchantDetail md where md.UserGUID = '" + UserGUID + "'", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            model.biz_dbaBusinessName = reader["biz_dbaBusinessName"].ToString();
                            merchList.Add(model);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }

        return View(merchList);
```